# Переписать процедуру на не случайную генерацию HEX 64

Tags: basic

Как можно изменить код на PureBasic так, чтобы результат не был случайным, а можно было указать вручную в код, с какого диапазона начать последовательность.
Значение должно быть в шестнадцатеричном формате hex, длина 64 символа

Например начинаем с a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fa5
и прибавляем по 1 бесконечно

получится

a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fa6
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fa7
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fa8
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fa9
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89faa
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fab
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fac
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fad
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fae
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89faf
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fb0
a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fb1

В этой процедуре всё выбирается случайно, но мне это не подходит.
Как её переписать, помогите кто знает.

```
Procedure.s NameGen()
  Protected Chars.s,Pos.a,Result.s,n.a
  Chars="abcdef"
  OpenCryptRandom()
  For n=1 To 64
    Select CryptRandom(1)
      Case 1
        Result+Str(CryptRandom(9))
      Case 0
        Pos=CryptRandom(Len(Chars))
        Result+Mid(Chars,Pos,1)
    EndSelect
  Next
  CloseCryptRandom()
  ProcedureReturn Result
EndProcedure
```

Comment: Определитесь все-таки с языком программирования. Basic и ассемблер слишком разные языки. И сочетаний возможных диалектов ассемблеров * операционных систем будет не менее 12 (это если только платформу x86 учитывать).

Comment: Задания, в т ч "по переводу" тут не делают. Как новичка - вас не заминусовали - это радует.

Comment: понял, тогда на Basic нужно это сделать, будет удобно читать код.

Answer (score 0):

```
Procedure IncChar(Array arr, pos)
  If pos < 0
    pos = ArraySize(arr) - 1
  EndIf
  ch = arr(pos)
  Select ch
    case "9" ch = "a"
    case "f"
      ch = "0"
      IncChar(arr, pos - 1)
    Default
      ch = Chr(Asc(ch) + 1)
  EndSelect
  arr(pos) = ch
EndProcedure

s = "a6707f09d6050dfdd368292b6c734a24fa22cef56b7b8fb08c262d6831e89fa5"
Dim arr.c(Len(s))

for i = 1 to Len(s)
  arr(i - 1) = Mid(s, i, 1)
Next

While True
  IncChar(arr, -1)
  Debug Join(arr, "")
Wend
```

Comment: PureBasic 5.40 LTS (Windows - x86) Попробовал скомпилировать, выдает синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: подозреваю, что это не тот язык для моей среды

Comment: @BTCMAKER В каком месте? Я писал на VBScript

Comment: @BTCMAKER Я подзреваю, что вам нужно изменить пару строчек для вашего бейсика. Как минимум, заменить вывод `WScript.echo`

Comment: прошу прощение, возможно ли так, что PBasic не понимает команд на VBscript

Comment: http://prntscr.com/r4m8qv

Comment: Все равно что то нет так, хотя свои коды компилирует без проблем.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/r4mcnz

Comment: http://prntscr.com/r4mdhy каждую строчку в синтаксис бьёт, не понимает язык

Comment: могу загрузить свою среду, попробуете сами

Comment: http://bigtracker.xyz/soft/584715-Purebasic_540_LTS_portable_Windows_x86_x64_2015_MULTILANG_RUS.html

Comment: не в какую не хочет http://prntscr.com/r4mnlb

Comment: @BTCMAKER поправил

Comment: это мне не помогло